Question about Proportionality in Sound Equation (Pressure and Displacement Amplitude)
Why is intensity in terms of pressure amplitude inversely proportional to density and velocity:
$I=\frac{\Delta p_\text{max}^2}{2\rho v}$,
while in terms of displacement amplitude, it is proportional to density and velocity:
$I=2\pi^2\rho vf^2s^2_\text{max}$

Have you looked into the derivations of these equations? They may provide some more insight into the answer you seek.

I did but I was wondering why can intensity both increase and decrease in response to a change in density and velocity, by considering either pressure or displacement. Or am I missing something? It feels like a contradiction

Both equations  are probably are a simplification. I say "probably" since you didn't define your symbols so I can only guess what it might mean.
The instantaneous intensity is simply
$$I(t) = p(t) \cdot v(t) \tag {1}$$
where $p$ is the pressure and $v$ is the particle velocity. If we assume free field conditions the velocity and pressure are related through the free field impedance, $Z_{free}$, of the medium which  is
$$Z_{free} = \rho \cdot c \tag{2}$$
where $c$ is the speed of propagation and $\rho$ the density. In free field conditions we have
$$ p(t) = \rho \cdot c \cdot v(t), v(t) = \frac{p(t)}{\rho \cdot c} \tag{3} $$
For the Intensity we can than write
$$I(t) = p(t) \cdot v(t) = \frac{p^2(t)}{\rho \cdot c } = \rho \cdot c \cdot v^2(t) \tag{4} $$
If you further assume a sine wave of frequency $omega$, i.e. $p(t) = p_{max}\cdot \cos(\omega t)$ we can calculate the average intensity as
$$<I(t)> =  <\frac{p^2(t)}{\rho \cdot c } > = \frac{p_{max}^2}{2 \rho \cdot c }  \tag{5}$$
If we want to express this through the displacement, s(t), we have to use the fact that the velocity is the first derivative of the displacement, i.e. $s(t) = \omega \cdot v_{max} \cdot \cos(\omega t)$
Using $\omega = 2\pi f$ and popping this into equation (4) you get something similar like your second equation.
The equations you quote are ONLY correct if you are in free field conditions and if you excite with a sine wave. If you are close to a boundary or source, these would NOT be correct anymore.

thank you for clarifying and pointing out my mistake

In case anyone else comes across this question, take a look at the following definition:
$p_\text{max}=\rho_0\omega vs_\text{max}$
which shows that $v$ is incorporated in the definition of the pressure amplitude, answering the given question

Sorry, this is only correct in free field conditions and if you are exciting with a sine wave. Generally this is NOT the case.
